# VS2017 "Extract Interface" has stopped working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Recently in Visual Studio 2017 (Professional) when I right context click on a class declaration to extract the interface, I now only get an error.  It used to work just fine.

Instead of extracting the interface, it gets this error instead(below)
I have not found anything with a web search related to this.
Any Ideas?

right click on class
[image: right click on class]

select Extract Interface
[image: select Extract Interface]

on the Extract Interface click SelectAll (if everything is not already selected)
then click OK
[image]

observe error
[image]

..and here is the stack trace.
[image]

It may have something to do with how many layers of folders the class is located in or the fact that the namespace.class does not match the file structure.
[image]

Any suggestions to get it working again?
Closing and reopening the solution, Visual Studio, or the restarting windows 10 does not help.

Comment: I run into errors like this with VS17 (e.g. can't create class, can't create project, hard crashes, etc). It seems to be an issue with the app data folder. I believe cached data is getting corrupt which breaks the application. The step I take to fix this sucks but works every time. Close VS and delete the 15.0.* folder in %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\. Hopefully this will fix your issue. NOTE: This will delete ALL your VS17 settings! You will need to re-configure the environment to your liking. I've created a clean base setting file to my liking that I import into VS17.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that my VS17 usually breaks after updating and deleting the 15.0.* folder has almost become part of my update process. Importing my settings file saves a lot of time.